# Derivation Control to output transfer function of switched capacitor dc-dc converter approach valid?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, switched-capacitor

For the control design, it is essential to have a plant model of the Switched-Capacitor-based DC-DC converter with a Voltage Conversion Ratio (VCR) of 1/3 implemented in a series-parallel topology. To derive the control-to-output transfer function (V_out(s)/f(s)), I have employed the averaged model, as depicted below:

[image]

Then I have derived the transfer functions in the following pictures:

[image]
[image]

Subsequently, I utilized MATLAB to input the data (VCR = 1/3, Vin = 4 V, Vout = 1.1 V, fsw = 4.89 MHz, Cout = 1 uF, Cfly = Ctotal = 3.8 nF) into the derived transfer functions and generated the corresponding Bode plots, which points will be later compared to the simulation.

Following that, I implemented the Series-Parallel Topology Switched-Capacitor-based DC-DC converter.
[image]
[image]

The Verilog-A code for the VCO has been written (not by me) and is available in the ahdblib in Cadence Virtuoso. The data for the ideal VCO is provided in the following image.
[image]

Subsequently, a comparator has been added to convert a sine wave to a square wave. When attempting to obtain the AC-gain and phase using PSS and PAC analysis, it does not yield the desired results as it gives me only 0 dB and 0 degrees, maybe because of the use of behavioural components written in verilogA. However, AC-gain and phase can be obtained by applying a small AC signal on top of the operating point and measuring at the output of the power stage. The results from MATLAB and manually performing AC analysis results at certain points are summarized in the tables.

**Verification of Vout(s)/Vin(s)**

[image]

**Verification of Vout(s)/Vctrl(s)**

[image]

Firstly, I have verified that Vout(s)/Vin(s) aligns with the simulation results. Secondly, I am unsure how to verify Vout(s)/f(s) as there is no direct way to simulate. Instead of Vout(s)/f(s), I added a VCO and comparator to obtain Vout(s)/Vctrl(s). Vctrl is the DC-input voltage of the ideal VCO. The simulation results align with the calculations, although the gain of Vout(s)/Vctrl(s) is approximately -9 to 11 dB off compared to the calculations. Does anyone know what the possible cause could be?

I have already checked my calculations several times for potential missing elements, including the VCO gain, which should be 5 MHz/V instead of 2π*5 MHz/V because the Verilog-A script of the VCO uses frequency units. Or is this approach just inaccurate to derive the dynamic behaviour of switched capacitor dc-dc converter?